# Remove File:/// before a folder path

Tags: c#, string, path

I have this code

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
```

This yields a string such as

```
"file://C://Foo//bin"
```

What I want is

```
"C://Foo//bin"
```

How do I get that without removing `"file://"` from the beginning manually?

Comment: Sorry if I'm completely misunderstanding, but doesn't Application.StartupPath get you what you need?

Comment: `path = path.Replace("file://", "")`.

Comment: What's wrong with removing it "manually"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Substring

```
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        this.Text = path.Substring(6, path.Length - 6);
```

or use this

```
this.Text = Application.StartupPath;
```

Comment: OP asked how can he achieve this WITHOUT removing it manually.